# Custom jQuery animation ignores its place in queue when chained and starts immediately

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

**Updated:**

I made a chainable animation effect plugin for jQuery (see my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BumbleB2na/pPxxZ/)). Within the custom effect, I use jquery's .animation() effect, which should place the animation in to jquery's built-in animation queue. When I try to chain animations it begins my custom  .horizontalBlinds() animation immediately, without placing it in jquery's built-in animation queue. How can I get it to wait its turn in a queue like all the other built-in jquery effects?

```
// both effects start at the same time
$(element).fadeIn().horizontalBlinds(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using fadeTo somehow

```
$('#element').hide().fadeTo(..., function() {
  $(this).fadeIn().horizontalBlinds(4);
});
```

Comment: thanks i tried but it does not help it out. I updated my question though, looks like my .horizontalBlinds() animation does not wait for its turn and starts same time as .fadeIn() animation

Comment: I could but I'm not sure how to detect how long it needs to delay. What I want is to use jQuery built in queue, and to find a way to get the .animation() queue property to work within my .horizontalBlinds() effect.